# How to Verify Whether Request Headers were Added by a Specific Web Application

Tags: security, encryption, web-applications, digital-signature, owasp

Currently I am working on a project which requires **high security**. Because of some recent requirement changes, we have added some special headers to each request using a front-end http intercepter(otherwise it would become a drastic change in front-end modules) and they are very critical for the system.

Recently we have observed that these headers can be modified using some browser plugins which is a critical issue. Hence I need a way to identify whether these headers contain the original values added from my front-end and they are not modified.

**Exposure of these header values is not a big concern. But modification is.**

.

.

**My Solution:**

1) Generate a RSA key pair each time module initializes and send the public key to a backend service with a unique id for that tab.

2) Keep the private key in a service in my front-end and create a public function to generate signature for a given input.

3) Each time the front-end intercepter is called, it will calculate a signature value based on the respective header values and append it as another header value.

4) When each request hit api gateway, it will verify the signature using the public key saved at the app initializing phase.

.

Are there concerned security risks for my above solution. If there is a better way of solving the above problem, suggestions are warmly welcomed :)

Comment: This is a very naive solution with zero security benefit (ie. it doesn't solve your problem). What you are trying to achieve is not possible. Any application running on the client **is** the user. You can think of it like your application is on the server, and the user may or may not use a programmed client to help him make requests, but the user can make _whatever request he wants_, and you cannot prevent that.

Comment: From a more practical standpoint, the user may want to use your app without modifying requests, or he may modify requests, or he may modify your app, or he may not use it at all... Whatever is in your app (like a generated RSA key) the user also has it. Whatever request your app makes, the user can also make it, after modifying it any way he wants. The bottomline is, your API must be secure, your client-side app cannot be secure against the user or infrastructure running it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using JWT for sending those headers... You may use symmetric signing (eg: HS256) or asymmetric signing (eg: RS256) depending on the whether you have ownership of both frontend and backend or front end is public...

For more details on creating JWT and Verifying it, please refer to https://jwt.io/

From the details, you had provided, this is the idea I got... For exact working, you have not provided whether it's web api or web application, etc.